# How to continue at particular step - spookyjs?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

I am using [spookyjs](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS) to test my application.

#### Question

Is there anyway to enforce the spookyJs to start at particular step?

How to force start at particular step `spookyJs`?

#### Example

`SpookyJs` will run step by step, Suppose some connection error happened at particular step and server got stopped, Now how can I continue the test from particular step instead of running from beginning.

Any suggestion will be grateful

Comment: one way would be to globally save the number of passed steps and recall the spookyjs funktion and passing the number of tests which have been done.